# Why didn't I get "Tumbleweed" for this question?

Tags: discussion, support, tumbleweed-badge

Low views, no comments, no answers, over a week old. I already have a previous tumbleweed question. Shouldn't I still get another tumbleweed?

[How to tell when a PHP Fatal Error is really a veiled Syntax Error, and when do they happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364800/how-to-tell-when-a-php-fatal-error-is-really-a-veiled-syntax-error-and-when-do-t)

Comment: Can we have a moratorium on "Why didn't I get this badge" - who cares why you didn't?

Comment: @Neil: Can we have a moratorium on "Can we have a moratorium on" - who cares if people want to learn?

Comment: I strongly suggest adding `[php]` tag to your question to get better attendance. Practically all SO users browse questions by tags.

Comment: @Neil, I care, that's why I asked it. This is a support forum as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you already have a tumbleweed badge. This badge is only awarded once.

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?user_id=260528

Comment: OK, the wording is a bit weird on the badge description. Thanks!